# extended and upright flags in SURF opencv c++ function

Tags: python, c++, opencv, image-processing, surf

what are the equivalent flags of SURF in opencv C++ to python SURF flags extended and upright ?

- in python version upright flag decides whether to calculate orientation or not
- And extended flag gives option of whether to use 64 dim or 128 dim

Is there a to do this similar operation in opencv C++ version of SURF function

FYI I am using opencv version 2.4.13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it !

C++: SURF::SURF(double hessianThreshold, int nOctaves=4, int nOctaveLayers=2, bool extended=true, bool upright=false )